# How can a coldblooded animal make an egg hatch?

Tags: eggs

I have chickens at home, and yesterday while removing the eggs I felt that they were quite warm. This seems to make sense, because the chicken has been brooding on it in order to make it hatch.

However now I wonder: next to chickens and/or other birds, there are other animals who are coldblooded and who are having eggs. Brooding on an egg means that the animal is delivering body temperature to the egg in order for the egg to grow and eventually produce a young animal. Now how can a coldblooded animal deliver body temperature if by definition, such an animal does not have body temperature?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The term cold-blooded is very misleading, you should have a look at [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/has-any-creature-ever-devolved-to-be-cold-blooded/19345#19345).

Comment: So-called "cold-blooded" animals say crocodiles and turtles lay eggs inside den or sand or mud etc. and normally not stay upon the eggs. Fishes and amphibians lay egg in water or certain specific substrate on water.  An interesting fact, commonly in case of reptiles the temperature plays a key role sex-determination.